# How do Lulu's "Help, Pix!" and Akali's "Twilight Shroud" interact?

Tags: league-of-legends

Will the stealth effects of Akali's [Twilight Shroud](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Akali_the_Fist_of_Shadow/Ability_Details) cancel the vision granting effects of Lulu's [Help, Pix!](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu_the_Fae_Sorceress/Ability_Details) spell?

Answer (score 5):

Lulu's "Help, Pix!" will grant you vision of Akali in her Twilight Shroud.  It will grant you vision of your target for the entire duration of the spell unless the target moves 2000 units away, at which point Pix will return to you.

Comment: Could you link a source and quote the relevant information?

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff mentioned Help, Pix! will not fade. Entering stealth will not remove any sight debuffs (such as Lee Sin's Tempest, or Lulu's Help, Pix!). This is the same for any stealth and any debuff.

Answer (score 1):

It grants vision as long as the effect last. Same with Shaco, Teemo, Eve, Twitch, Vayne